# Why is a custom field not appearing in forms after changing its type from CheckBox to Select?

Tags: custom-fields, forms

A custom field was originally created as HTML type CheckBox (with Options Per Line set). This was later changed to type Select, using the *Change Input Field Type* facility in the Edit Field form. After this change, the field fails to appear in edit forms: the label displays but the Select field is  missing.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if a Select field has `options_per_line` set in `civicrm_custom_field`, then it fails to render, as described. A workaround is to unset Options Per Line in the UI before changing the field type, or set `options_per_line` to NULL in the database. The Select field then renders as it should.